# How to parse two json arrary in single activity?

Tags: java, android

I have JSON array response. But I can't parse this JSON array. I tried many times but always showing me a single array. Help me to find this error.

**View_product.java**

```
   public void View_products(final String user_id) {

        final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(View_product_Activity.this);
        progress.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,  GLOBAL.baseURL+ "userProducts.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        Log.d("productData", s.toString());
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);
                            int status = json.getInt("status");

                            if(status==0) {

                                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("productData");
                                ArrayList<Product_view> productModel = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)  {
                                    Product_view product_view = new Product_view();
                                    JSONObject localJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                                    product_view.setUser_id(localJson.getString("user_id"));
                                    product_view.setProduct_id(localJson.getString("product_id"));
                                    product_view.setProductName(localJson.getString("productName"));
                                    product_view.setProductDesc(localJson.getString("productDesc"));
                                    product_view.setTotal_subproduct(localJson.getString("total_subproduct"));


                                    JSONArray sub_product = localJson.getJSONArray("sub_product");
                                        for(int j = 0 ; j < sub_product.length(); j++){
                                        JSONObject subproductobject =sub_product.getJSONObject(j);

                                    product_view.setSub_product(subproductobject.getString("sub_product"));
                                    product_view.setSubproduct_id(subproductobject.getString("subproduct_id"));
                                    product_view.setSubProductName(subproductobject.getString("subProductName"));
                                    product_view.setCert_type(subproductobject.getString("cert_type"));
                                    product_view.setAmount_paid(subproductobject.getString("amount_paid"));
                                    product_view.setPurchased_date(subproductobject.getString("purchased_date"));
                                    product_view.setExpiry_date(subproductobject.getString("expiry_date"));
                                    product_view.setExpire_status(subproductobject.getString("expire_status"));


                                    productModel.add(product_view);


                                    if (status==0){

                                    }else {

                                        }
                                    }

                                }

                            } else {

                                Log.d("Login", s.toString());
                                progress.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "YOU HAVE ONE ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            progress.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

**my json response.**

```
"status": "0",
"productData": [

    {
        "user_id": "20",
        "product_id": "5",
        "productName": "NCC Test Series",
        "productDesc": "NCC test series is a very popular product which has three sub products. i.e. Multiple Choice question (MCQ), MCQ + Subjective, Combo Pack",
        "total_subproduct": "11",


        "sub_product": 

[
            {
                "subproduct_id": "10",
                "subProductName": "MCQ + Subjective",
                "cert_type": "C",
                "amount_paid": "1000/-",
                "purchased_date": "03-01-2019",
                "expiry_date": "03-01-2020",
                "expire_status": "No"
            },

            {
                "subproduct_id": "9",
                "subProductName": "Multiple Choice question",
                "cert_type": "B",
                "amount_paid": "1000/-",
                "purchased_date": "03-01-2019",
                "expiry_date": "03-01-2020",
                "expire_status": "No"
            },


            {
                "subproduct_id": "17",
                "subProductName": "Multiple Choice question",
                "cert_type": "C",
                "amount_paid": "1180.00/-",
                "purchased_date": "09-01-2019",
                "expiry_date": "09-01-2020",
                "expire_status": "No"
            }
    ]


    }
]
```

}

**log**

```
11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp D/productData: {"status":"0","productData":[{"user_id":"20","product_id":"5","productName":"NCC Test Series","productDesc":"NCC test series is a very popular product which has three sub products. i.e. Multiple Choice question (MCQ), MCQ + Subjective, Combo Pack","total_subproduct":"11","sub_product":[{"subproduct_id":"10","subProductName":"MCQ + Subjective","cert_type":"C","amount_paid":"1000\/-","purchased_date":"03-01-2019","expiry_date":"03-01-2020","expire_status":"No"},{"subproduct_id":"9","subProductName":"Multiple Choice question","cert_type":"B","amount_paid":"1000\/-","purchased_date":"03-01-2019","expiry_date":"03-01-2020","expire_status":"No"},{"subproduct_id":"8","subProductName":"MCQ + Subjective","cert_type":"B","amount_paid":"1000\/-","purchased_date":"03-01-2019","expiry_date":"03-01-2020","expire_status":"No"},{"subproduct_id":"7","subProductName":"MCQ + Subjective","cert_type":"A","amount_paid":"1000\/-","purchased_date":"29-12-2018","expiry_date":"29-12-2019","expire_status":"No"},{"subproduct_id":"11","subProductName":"MCQ + Subjective","cert_type":"A","amount_paid":"1180\/-","purchased_date":"03-01-2019","expiry_date":"03-01-2020","expire_status":"No"},{"subproduct_id":"12","subProductName":"Combo Pack","cert_type":"B","amount_paid":"1770\/-","purchased_date":"09-01-2019","expiry_date":"09-01-2020","expire_status":"No"},{"subproduct_id":"13","subProductName":"Combo Pack","cert_type":"B","amount_paid":"1770\/-","purchased_date":"09-01-2019","expiry_date":"09-01-2020","expire_status":"No"},{"subproduct_id":"14","subProductName":"Combo Pack","cert_type":"C","amount_paid":"50.00\/-","purchased_date":"09-01-2019","expiry_date":"09-01-2020","expire_status":"No"},{"subproduct_id":"15","subProductName":"Combo Pack","cert_type":"B","amount_paid":"50.00\/-","purchased_date":"09-01-2019","expiry_date":"09-01-2020","expire_status":"No"},{"subproduct_id":"16","subProductName":"MCQ + Subjective","cert_type":"B","amount_paid":"50.00\/-","purchased_date":"09-01-2019","expiry_date":"09-01-2020","expire_status":"No"},{"subproduct_id":"17","subProductName":"Multiple Choice question","cert_type":"C","amount_paid":"1180.00\/-","purchased_date":"09-01-2019","expiry_date":"09-01-2020","expire_status":"No"}]}]}
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for sub_product
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at com.tsa.nccapp.View_product_Activity$3.onResponse(View_product_Activity.java:218)
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at com.tsa.nccapp.View_product_Activity$3.onResponse(View_product_Activity.java:190)
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
01-25 15:56:32.991 11546-11546/com.tsa.nccapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-25 15:56:33.551 11546-13315/com.tsa.nccapp V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: You have an error in your code: `product_view.setSub_product(subproductobject.getString("sub_product"));` The subproduct doesn't have a sub_product item.

Answer (score 0):

For more simplicity and flexibily you can use the Gson Library from Google to parse Json Array/Object : https://github.com/google/gson

If you don't want to us it you need to check if all field are null before getString()

Good luck !